# BitBucket pipeline: Unable to pull private ECR image after login

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, amazon-ecr

I have a BitBucket pipeline I am using to push a docker image into ECR. I am using a custom private build environment that I was able to push into ECR, but for some reason I'm unable to use that build environment in my pipeline. I am able to login to the ECR repo, but after login succeeds, I am getting unable to pull image and docker login may be required. Any advice on how to pull after logging in would be helpful.

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image:
  name: xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/awscli/kubectl
  aws:
    access-key: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    secret-key: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
definitions:
step: &push
    name: Push Docker Image to ECR
    script:
      - ecr_scripts/login.sh
      - docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE .
      - pipe: atlassian/aws-ecr-push-image:1.3.0
        variables:
          IMAGE_NAME: $DOCKER_IMAGE
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-2

  step: &deploy
    name: Deploy to EKS
    deployment: development
    script:
      - aws eks --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION update-kubeconfig --name $EKS_CLUSTER
      - kubectl rollout --namespace $NS restart deployments $DEPLOYMENT

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *push
      - step: *deploy

    staging:
      - step: *push
      - step: *deploy

    production:
      - step:
          <<: *push
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-ecr-push-image:1.3.0
              variables:
                IMAGE_NAME: $DOCKER_IMAGE
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-west-2"
      - step: *deploy
```

**Login Succeeded**

```
+ ecr_scripts/login.sh
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
```

**Docker Build fail**

```
+ docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.794MB
Step 1/7 : FROM xxx/xxx
pull access denied for xxx/xxx, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Answer (score 1):

I use an alternative method to build and push Docker images to AWS ECR:

```
image: amazon/aws-cli
options:
  docker: true
oidc: true
aws:
  oidc-role: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/BitBucket-ECR-Access

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and push to ECR
        script:
          - aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
          - docker build -t 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myimage:0.0.1 .
          - docker push 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myimage:0.0.1
```

You will need to update the role ARN to match a Role you have created in your AWS IAM console with sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `aws-ecr-push-image` pipe supports 2 OPTIONS for Authentication:

1. Environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. Default option.
2. Assume role provider with OpenID Connect (OIDC)

***Note***: it doesnot support Authentication via command line as you put above: `login.sh`. You are using plugin `aws-ecr-push-image` for authentication to push/pull image.

In this case, we are using the first one. So you have to add:

```
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

in `variables` in:

```
script:
  # build the image
  - docker build -t my-docker-image .

  # use the pipe to push the image to AWS ECR
  - pipe: atlassian/aws-ecr-push-image:1.3.0
    variables:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
      IMAGE_NAME: my-docker-image
```

Reference: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-ecr-push-image/src/master/

Comment: Hi @Thanh Nguyen Van, thank you for your response. I do not have those variables integrated in my file because I have specified as repository variables. Those variables can be overwritten in the actual file when specified. In this case I have those being read in as repository variables. I am receiving the same error when also specifying them in the file.